# Expand view location to class library folder in ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, razorengine

Consider, I have two projects as follows:

1. Test.Application (Class Library)
2. Test.Web (ASP.NET Core web application project)

In `Test.Application` project, there is a folder called `EmailTemplates` which contains all the email templates(`.cshmtl` files).

By default, ASP.NET Core Razor View Engine only search views in the `Views` folder of the `Test.Web` project. How can I configure that Razor View Engine will also search views in the `EmailTemplates` folder of the `Test.Application` class library project.

Thank you.

Comment: This might be helpful https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-3.1#view-discovery

Comment: You are basically looking for a custom `IViewLocationExpander`

Comment: @Nkosi Yes! But it should point to the `EmailTemplates` folder of the `Test.Application` class library project.

Comment: @Nkosi Could you help me please in this regard?

Comment: I did some research to see what are the available options. Looks like you may need to make some changes. Check this from the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio.

Comment: @Nkosi Thank you for your time! Actually I am aware of the Razor Class Library project but I wanted this without converting the existing class library project to a Razor Class Library project.